# jQuery Autocomplete rendertem__ Cant Return Value Within If Statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Trying to render a search list with jQuery Autocomplete however my goal is that once a list item is appended to the page (a user selects an item, and a user can select multiple items) the user is unable to search for that same item.

HTML CODE

```
                 <div id='feature-searchbar'>
                        <label for='feature-search'>Search for applicable features...</label>
                        <input id="feature-search-input" type="text" name="featureSearch-input" placeholder="Search for applicable features..." class="feature__search-input ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
                    
                    <div id='feature-results'>
                
                //Selected items go here
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Right now trying to go about it by adding a class to a rendered item if it is already present in the appended page. Using jQuery I target the  on the page where the items will appear if a user were to select one and target the data-type. Tell my jQuery 'if the datatype is already present, add a class' however I cant seem to return the value outside of the if statement.

jQuery

```
                      jQuery("#feature-search-input").autocomplete({
                                appendTo: "#feature-searchbar",
                                source: function (req, res) {
                                    jQuery.ajax({
                                        url: myAPI
                                        data: {
                                            term: jQuery("#feature-search-input").val(),
                                            
                                        },
                                        type: "GET",
                                        datatype: 'json',
                                        crossOrigin: true,
                                        success: function (data) {

                                        // set results to top 6 only
                                        data.length = Math.min(data.length, 5);

                                        
                                        var items = data;

                                        var search_term = jQuery("#feature-search-input").val();

                                        items.push({

                                            label: `<?php _e('More search results for'); ?> "${ search_term }"`,
                                            value: search_term,
                                            more_results: true

                                        });
                                        res(items);
                                        
                                        }
                                    });
                                },
                                select: function(event, ui) {

                                

                                    var featureListItem = `<div class="feature-list-item" data-id="${ui.item.id}">
                                                                <input type='hidden' name='content-feature-ids[]' value='${ui.item.id}'>
                                                                <p>${ ui.item.short_desc }</p> 
                                                                <a class='content-feature-remove'>Remove<a/>
                                                            </div>`;

                                    
                                //append to page
                                jQuery('#feature-results').append(featureListItem);

                                    
                                //removal 
                                    jQuery(".content-feature-remove").click(function (e) {
                                        jQuery(this).parent().remove(); 

                                    });


                                    jQuery("#feature-search-input").val('');


                                }
                            }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {

                                //TODO: check if item exists within feature-results, do not render it

                                //if item is rendered onto feature-results { add: class which tells user it has already been selected}
                                var item_label = '';

                                //need to validate items somehow so they do not get selected twice
                                
                                

                                if (item.id && item.short_desc) {

                                    item_label = `
                                                    <div class='rendered-feature-item' data-id="${item.id}">
                                                        <p>${ item.short_desc }</p>     
                                                    </div>  
                                                    `;          
                                } else { 
                                    item_label = `<strong>No Results</strong>`;
                                }

//need to validate items somehow so they do not get selected twice
//target the html and check if data-type is same as item.id

                                var existing_feature = jQuery(`#feature-results .feature-list-item[data-id="${item.id}"]`)
                                var existing_feature_id = 0;
                                var variable = '';
                                if (existing_feature !== undefined && existing_feature !== null) { 
                                    existing_feature_id = existing_feature.data('id');
                                    if (existing_feature_id !== undefined && existing_feature_id !== null) {
                                        console.log(existing_feature_id);

                                        var potential_existing = jQuery('.rendered-feature-item[data-id="'+existing_feature_id+'"]');
                                        var potential_existing_id = potential_existing;
                                        return existing_feature_id;
                                    }
                                    return existing_feature_id;
                                }   

//here is where I get errors, code does not recognize existing_feature_id
                                        
                                   var potential_existing_id = existing_feature_id
var potential_existing_item = jQuery('.rendered-feature-item[data-id="'+potential_existing_id+'"]')


                                    potential_existing_item.css('color', 'red');

                                            

                                return jQuery( '<li>' )
                                .attr( "data-value", item.id )
                                .append( item_label )
                                .appendTo( ul );
                            };

                        
                        });
```

Reason I have to run a if statement is that the id variable is coming back as the id however also as "undefined" at the same time
Currently getting an error that states
Uncaught TypeError: this._renderItem(...).data is not a function

Comment: Take a look at this Demo: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple This allows multiple items to be selected. What you need to add, in your `source` will be to filter out previous selected items.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example. This is loosely related to https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var availableFeatures = [{
      label: "ActionScript",
      value: "ActionScript",
      id: "1"
    },
    {
      label: "AppleScript",
      value: "AppleScript",
      id: "2"
    },
    {
      label: "Asp",
      value: "Asp",
      id: "3"
    },
    {
      label: "BASIC",
      value: "BASIC",
      id: "4"
    },
    {
      label: "C",
      value: "C",
      id: "5"
    }
  ];

  function getFeatures(apiUrl, searchTerm) {
    var results;
    $.ajax({
      url: apiUrl,
      data: {
        term: searchTerm,
      },
      type: "GET",
      datatype: 'json',
      crossOrigin: true,
      success: function(data) {
        results = data;
      }
    });
    return results;
  }

  function filterResults(fArr, results) {
    $.each(fArr, function(i, el) {
      var index = results.map(function(e) {
        return e.label;
      }).indexOf(el);
      if (index > -1) {
        results.splice(index, 1);
      }
    });
    return results;
  }

  function getCurrentFeatures(target) {
    var features = [];
    $(".feature-list-item", target).each(function(i, el) {
      features.push($("p", el).text().trim());
    });
    return features;
  }

  function addFeature(item) {
    var featureItem = $("<div>", {
      class: "feature-list-item"
    }).data("feature-id", item.id);
    $("<p>").html(item.label).appendTo(featureItem);
    $("<a>", {
      class: "content-feature-remove",
      title: "Remove Feature"
    }).html("X").appendTo(featureItem);
    $("#feature-results").append(featureItem);
    if ($("#selectedFeatures").val() == "") {
      $("#selectedFeatures").val(item.id);
    } else {
      var selected = $("#selectedFeatures").val().split(",");
      selected.push(item.id);
      $("#selectedFeatures").val(selected.join(","));
    }
  }

  function removeFeature(item) {
    var thisId = $(item).closest(".feature-list-item").data("feature-id");
    console.log("Remove Feature", thisId);
    $(item).parent().remove();
    var selected = $("#selectedFeatures").val().split(",");
    var index = selected.indexOf(thisId);
    console.log(selected, index);
    if (index > -1) {
      selected.splice(index, 1);
    }
    $("#selectedFeatures").val(selected.join(","));
  }

  $("#feature-search-input").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      // Example og getting data
      // var myData = getFeatures("/results", request.term);

      var myData = availableFeatures;
      myData = filterResults(getCurrentFeatures("#feature-results"), myData);
      myData = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(myData, request.term);
      response(myData);
    },
    focus: function() {
      return false;
    },
    select: function(e, ui) {
      addFeature(ui.item);
      $(this).val("").autocomplete("search", "");
      return false;
    }
  });

  $("#feature-results").on("click", ".content-feature-remove", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    removeFeature(this);
  });

  /*$("#feature-search-input").autocomplete({
    appendTo: "#feature-searchbar",
    source: function(req, res) {
      $.ajax({
        url: myAPI
        data: {
          term: $("#feature-search-input").val(),
        },
        type: "GET",
        datatype: 'json',
        crossOrigin: true,
        success: function(data) {
          var items = [];
          items.push({
            label: data.label,
            value: data.value
          });
          res(items);
        }
      });
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      var featureListItem = `<div class="feature-list-item" data-id="${ui.item.id}"><input type='hidden' name='content-feature-ids[]' value='${ui.item.id}'><p>${ ui.item.short_desc }</p><a class='content-feature-remove'>Remove<a/></div>`;
      $('#feature-results').append(featureListItem);
      $(".content-feature-remove").click(function(e) {
        $(this).parent().remove();
      });
      $("#feature-search-input").val('');
    }
  }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    var item_label = '';
    if (item.id && item.short_desc) {
      item_label = `<div class='rendered-feature-item' data-id="${item.id}"><p>${ item.short_desc }</p></div>`;
    } else {
      item_label = `<strong>No Results</strong>`;
    }
    var existing_feature = $(`#feature-results .feature-list-item[data-id="${item.id}"]`);
    var existing_feature_id = 0;
    var variable = '';
    if (existing_feature !== undefined && existing_feature !== null) {
      existing_feature_id = existing_feature.data('id');
      if (existing_feature_id !== undefined && existing_feature_id !== null) {
        console.log(existing_feature_id);
        var potential_existing = jQuery('.rendered-feature-item[data-id="' + existing_feature_id + '"]');
        var potential_existing_id = potential_existing;
        return existing_feature_id;
      }
      return existing_feature_id;
    }
    var potential_existing_id = existing_feature_id
    var potential_existing_item = jQuery('.rendered-feature-item[data-id="' + potential_existing_id + '"]')
    potential_existing_item.css('color', 'red');
    return jQuery('<li>')
      .attr("data-value", item.id)
      .append(item_label)
      .appendTo(ul);
  };
  */
});
```

```css
.feature-list-item {
  border: 1px solid #9f9f9f;
  border-radius: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.feature-list-item p {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 3px;
  color: #2f2f2f;
}

.content-feature-remove {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #999;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id='feature-searchbar'>
  <label for='feature-search'>Search for applicable features...</label>
  <input id="feature-search-input" type="text" name="featureSearch-input" placeholder="Search for applicable features..." class="feature__search-input ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
  <div id='feature-results'></div>
  <input id="selectedFeatures" type="hidden" name="content-feature-ids" />
</div>
```

Considering that your AJAX will come back with an Array of Objects, I setup the example to work on this case.

When the User selects an item, it adds it to a list, and updates a text field. As more items are added or removed, the text field is updated with the IDs for each feature.

The suggestion list will filter the results and will exclude any that have already been selected.

The snippet cannot show AJAX. You will see a function to help get the data from PHP. Run it like so:

```
var myFeatures = getFeatures("/features.php", "feature");
```

This will perform a GET request of the URL supplied with the search term. Your PHP will want to return an Array of Objects:

```
[{
  label: "Feature 1",
  value: "Feature 1"
  id: "f001"
}];
```

You can have more parameters than 'id' if you want, yet you must have `label` and `value` for autocomplete.

> An array of objects with label and value properties: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]

My example makes use of the following line:

```
myData = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(myData, request.term);
```

You can omit this line in your script as PHP should be filtering the results for you.